# Filamentphp Admin Panel Render nearly after 5minutes in Cpanel

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-filament, filamentphp

[After Login dashboard became black screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdqsB.png)

When accessing the admin panel, it occasionally displays as a black screen without loading properly. Sometimes it resolves itself after about 5 minutes, but other times it remains stuck. No errors are showing in the console. What steps can I take to resolve this issue?

#### If you want to try login, here are the details.

**URL:** [https://filament.followfam.com](https://filament.followfam.com/auth/login)
**Username:**  `exchanger@gmail.com`
**Password:** `exchanger@gmail.com`

> Try two or three times or visit other pages if the admin panel renders successfully first then this problem happens.

It should render less a second but it's not doing this and create this problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -3):

The issue is with the livewire config file. There are some changes that need to be done.

This is what the config file should look like:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Class Namespace
    |---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value sets the root class namespace for Livewire component classes in
    | your application. This value will change where component auto-discovery
    | finds components. It's also referenced by the file creation commands.
    |
    */

    'class_namespace' => 'App\\Livewire',

    /*
    |---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | View Path
    |---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value is used to specify where Livewire component Blade templates are
    | stored when running file creation commands like `artisan make:livewire`.
    | It is also used if you choose to omit a component's render() method.
    |
    */

    'view_path' => resource_path('views/livewire'),

    /*
    |---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Layout
    |---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | The view that will be used as the layout when rendering a single component
    | as an entire page via `Route::get('/post/create', CreatePost::class);`.
    | In this case, the view returned by CreatePost will render into $slot.
    |
    */

    'layout' => 'components.layouts.app',

    /*
    |---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Lazy Loading Placeholder
    |---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Livewire allows you to lazy load components that would otherwise slow down
    | the initial page load. Every component can have a custom placeholder or
    | you can define the default placeholder view for all components below.
    |
    */

    'lazy_placeholder' => null,

    /*
    |---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Temporary File Uploads
    |---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Livewire handles file uploads by storing uploads in a temporary directory
    | before the file is stored permanently. All file uploads are directed to
    | a global endpoint for temporary storage. You may configure this below:
    |
    */

    'temporary_file_upload' => [
        'disk' => null,        // Example: 'local', 's3'              | Default: 'default'
        'rules' => null,       // Example: ['file', 'mimes:png,jpg']  | Default: ['required', 'file', 'max:12288'] (12MB)
        'directory' => null,   // Example: 'tmp'                      | Default: 'livewire-tmp'
        'middleware' => null,  // Example: 'throttle:5,1'             | Default: 'throttle:60,1'
        'preview_mimes' => [   // Supported file types for temporary pre-signed file URLs...
            'png', 'gif', 'bmp', 'svg', 'wav', 'mp4',
            'mov', 'avi', 'wmv', 'mp3', 'm4a',
            'jpg', 'jpeg', 'mpga', 'webp', 'wma',
        ],
        'max_upload_time' => 5, // Max duration (in minutes) before an upload is invalidated...
    ],

    /*
    |---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Render On Redirect
    |---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value determines if Livewire will run a component's `render()` method
    | after a redirect has been triggered using something like `redirect(...)`
    | Setting this to true will render the view once more before redirecting
    |
    */

    'render_on_redirect' => false,

    /*
    |---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Eloquent Model Binding
    |---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Previous versions of Livewire supported binding directly to eloquent model
    | properties using wire:model by default. However, this behavior has been
    | deemed too "magical" and has therefore been put under a feature flag.
    |
    */

    'legacy_model_binding' => false,

    /*
    |---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Auto-inject Frontend Assets
    |---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By default, Livewire automatically injects its JavaScript and CSS into the
    | <head> and <body> of pages containing Livewire components. By disabling
    | this behavior, you need to use @livewireStyles and @livewireScripts.
    |
    */

    'inject_assets' => true,

    /*
    |---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Navigate (SPA mode)
    |---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By adding `wire:navigate` to links in your Livewire application, Livewire
    | will prevent the default link handling and instead request those pages
    | via AJAX, creating an SPA-like effect. Configure this behavior here.
    |
    */

    'navigate' => [
        'show_progress_bar' => true,
        'progress_bar_color' => '#2299dd',
    ],

    /*
    |---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTML Morph Markers
    |---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Livewire intelligently "morphs" existing HTML into the newly rendered HTML
    | after each update. To make this process more reliable, Livewire injects
    | "markers" into the rendered Blade surrounding @if, @class & @foreach.
    |
    */

    'inject_morph_markers' => false,

    /*
    |---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Pagination Theme
    |---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When enabling Livewire's pagination feature by using the `WithPagination`
    | trait, Livewire will use Tailwind templates to render pagination views
    | on the page. If you want Bootstrap CSS, you can specify: "bootstrap"
    |
    */

    'pagination_theme' => 'tailwind',
];
```

Comment: I didn't change any configuration of Livewire. There are default configuration that comes with the package.